# Searching approach to create a function

Tags: functions

there is this number row called "triangular numbers"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number
(1, 3, 6, 10 ...)

$$
f(n)=(n(n+1))/2 
$$
$$
n\in\ N 
$$

i want to create a function g(n), so that it "counts" the 
triangle numbers until n.
So g(1) == g(2) should result 1, g(3) == g(4) == g(5) == 2,
g(6) == g(7) == g(8) == g(9) == 3 and so on.

Is there a way to achieve something like that? I don't want a final solution,
but im struggling finding a general approach at all.

Answer (score 2):

You want the inverse of $f$ or at least something close to it. Note that $g(f(n)) = n$ and $f(g(x)) = x$ when $x$ is a triangular number. The difference between the inverse of $f$ and $g$ is that $g$ is always an integer. In fact since $f$ and the inverse of $f$ are increasing, it can be shown that $g$ is the floor of the inverse of $f$. So,

$$g(x) = \left\lfloor-\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+2x}\right\rfloor$$.

Comment: You made an error in computing the inverse of $f$. You want $(1/2)n^2+(1/2)n=x$ and $n \geq 0$ so $n=-1/2+\sqrt{1/4+2x}$. If desired you can leave the $2$ in the denominator, which yields the coefficients you used...but then you still have a sign error.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I try to make it myself the same way :)